# How to Increase font size on LG optimus g pro notepad, not the whole phone

Tags: lg

I am setting up a LG Optimus G Pro, and the notepad, both in this widget thing, and in the application itself is hard to read (on the smaller screen).

I know where the phones font size and accessability features are, but I do not wish to increase the size of all the fonts, for example the settings text is large enough.

I had the font on the notepad much bigger, but I cannot find the settings for the notepad itself, tried the menu button, and all the buttons shown.
I attempted searching for this with google , but came up with nothing.

[image]

I am hoping that somone with this actual model, knows how I had the fonts there large, without an additional app or changing the overall font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

[*Phone needs to be rooted*] In case you're interested in an app solution, try [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and [App Settings](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2437377).

**What is Xposed Installer?**

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the
>   system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it
>   means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs
>   without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too
>   much). It's also easy to undo. As all changes are done in the memory,
>   you just need to deactivate the module and reboot to get your original
>   system back. There are many other advantages, but here is just one
>   more: Multiple modules can do changes to the same part of the system
>   or app. With modified APKs, you to decide for one. No way to combine
>   them, unless the author builds multiple APKs with different
>   combinations.

**What are some of the things that App Settings can change?**

- DPI: Changes the DPI used by this app both when loading resources (some might be DPI-specific) and also when rendering them.
- Font Scale: Scales the font up or down, similarly to the system-wide "Font Size" setting.